# How to get some number by different groups using re module in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Assume that there is a string like `s = 'add/10/20/30/4/3/9/'` or `s = 'add/10/20/30/'`, which starts with `'add'`, and follows many numbers(not sure how many, only know 3 times repeat at least).

I wanted to got them in: ['10', '20', ...]
I tried to use re: `r = re.compile(r"add/(?:(\d+)/){3,}")`
However, only the last number matched and returned.

```
>>> r.findall(s)
['9']
```

So what's the problem and how to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need `re` module. Use `s.split("/")[1:-1]`

Answer (score 3):

Is regex a must? string split method should be faster here if you have such simple patterns:

```py
s = "add/10/20/30/4/3/9/"
nums = [num for num in s.split('/')[1:] if num]
```

regex pattern would be smply:

```py
re.findall('\d+', s)
```

Comment: added regex version... just consider: if you have to do this like a million times, save performance by using simple list comprehension / split method

Answer (score 0):

This would return all the numerical sequence in string `s`.

```
re.findall(r"[0-9]+", s)
```